# Equations of the spherical pendulum in different coordinates

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators, anharmonic-oscillators

I am trying to derive the equations of motion of a spherical pendulum, but instead of using the angles of the spherical coordinate system $\theta$ and $\varphi$, I want to use the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$, defined such that the position of the pendulum at a given time can be seen as the result of a rotation $\alpha$ around the $x$ axis and $\beta$ around the $y$ axis.

My attempt is the following. I have the Lagrangian:

$$L=mgl\cos\!\alpha\cos\!\beta+\frac{1}{2}m(l\cos\!\beta\;\dot\alpha)^2+\frac{1}{2}m(l\cos\!\alpha\;\dot\beta)^2,$$

writing -potential + kinetic for simplicity, and taking the zero of the vertical position at the pivot point of the pendulum. This gives me the following equations of motion:

$$\cos\!\beta\;\ddot\alpha=-\frac{g}{l}\sin\alpha+2\sin\!\beta\;\dot\alpha\dot\beta$$
$$\cos\!\alpha\;\ddot\beta =-\frac{g}{l}\sin\beta +2\sin\!\alpha\;\dot\beta\dot\alpha $$

But as the choice of coordinates is a bit funny here, I'm afraid of doing a mistake somewhere! Could someone knowledgeable of pendula check that this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the position vector of a spherical pendulum is:

$$\mathbf R_s=S_z(\theta)\,S_y(\phi)\,\begin{bmatrix}
       0 \\
       0 \\
       l
     \end{bmatrix}=l\, \left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( \theta \right) \sin \left( \phi
 \right) \\ \sin \left( \theta \right) \sin \left( 
\phi \right) \\  \cos \left( \phi \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

you want to obtain the position vector with this two rotation

$$\mathbf R_p=S_x(\alpha)\,S_y(\beta)\,\begin{bmatrix}
       0 \\
       0 \\
       l
     \end{bmatrix}=l\, \left[ \begin {array}{c} \sin \left( \beta \right) 
\\ -\sin \left( \alpha \right) \cos \left( \beta
 \right) \\ \cos \left( \alpha \right) \cos \left( 
\beta \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

with $~\mathbf R_s=\mathbf R_p~$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\phi=\arccos \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right) \cos \left( \beta \right) 
 \right)$$
$$\theta=\arccos \left( {\frac {\sin \left( \beta \right) }{\sqrt {1- \left( 
\cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( \cos \left( \beta
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}} \right) 
$$

thus

$$\mathbf R_s=l\,\left[ \begin {array}{c} \sin \left( \beta \right) 
\\ i\,\sin(\alpha)\,\cos \left( \beta \right) \\ \cos
 \left( \alpha \right) \cos \left( \beta \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

from here you obtain the kinetic energy

$$T=l^2\,\frac 12\,m \left( {\dot\beta }^{2}+ \left( \cos \left( \beta \right) 
 \right) ^{2}{\dot\alpha }^{2} \right)
$$

the potential enegry

$$U=m\,g\,l\,\cos \left( \alpha \right) \cos \left( \beta \right)$$

and the equations of motion

$$\begin{bmatrix}
       \ddot \alpha \\
       \ddot \beta \\
     \end{bmatrix}= \left[ \begin {array}{c} {\frac {2\,l\dot\alpha \,\sin \left( \beta
 \right) \dot\beta +g\sin \left( \alpha \right) }{l\cos \left( \beta
 \right) }}\\ {\frac {\sin \left( \beta \right) 
 \left( -l\cos \left( \beta \right) {\dot\alpha }^{2}+g\cos \left( \alpha
 \right)  \right) }{l}}\end {array} \right] 
$$

notice that one of the components of  $~\mathbf R_s(\alpha~,\beta)~$ has a complex value, this doesn't make sense !!

Comment: Thanks! I don't get this complex value thing but using directly your expression of $R_p$ and differentiating in time I could get the same kinetic energy than you. Just, I don't get the same $\ddot\beta$ in the end, I have $\ddot\beta=-g/l\sin\beta\cos\alpha$ instead...

Comment: your kinetic energy is not the same as mine?

Comment: I do, what I have different is the expression of $\ddot\beta$ at the end.

Comment: you are right , i have wrong sign in the potential energy, put g=-g in my equations.